# how to prevent a re-rendering of a variable that is not being used in the HTML of my vue.js component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to recreate a real example of my code.
In my real code, this line is actually a `component` that will `fetch` an endpoint every few seconds, and fetch a random array of `"n"` length, `myData` it will contain these fetch.

```
<div v-for="item in addingData(myData)">  <!-- in My real code, "myData" should be the answer of an endpoint, is an setInterval, returns data like [{id:1},{id:2}] -->
  {{ item.id }}
</div>
```

I am simulating that the response changes in `myData` with the help of `setTimeOut`

```
mounted() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('First data');
    this.myData = [{ id: 3 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 1 }];
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('second data');
      this.myData = [{ id: 4 }, { id: 4 }];
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Third data');
        this.myData = [];
      }, 3000);
    }, 3000);
  }, 2000);
},
```

I am trying to make that every time I receive data in `myData`, the list of the concatenation of the received data is shown without having repeated data. That's why every time I receive data, that calls the function `addingData(myData)` that will do this data concatenation.
I'm using the function `v-for="item in addingData(myData)` and `auxData` is the variable that will do this concatenation.

why when there is new data, the addingData function is called 2 times and how can I prevent it?

[image]

in terms of performance this should be the output in the `console.log`:

[image]

what causes this re-rendering and how can I avoid it?

this is my live code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-l7gdpj?file=src%2FApp.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="item in addingData(myData)">
      {{ item.id }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      myData: [],
      auxData: [],
    };
  },
    mounted() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('First data');
        this.myData = [{ id: 3 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 1 }];
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('second data');
          this.myData = [{ id: 4 }, { id: 4 }];
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Third data');
            this.myData = [];
          }, 3000);
        }, 3000);
      }, 2000);
    },
  methods: {
    addingData(getDataFetch) {
      console.log('Entering AddingData', getDataFetch);
      if (getDataFetch.length !== 0) {
        if (this.auxData.length === 0) {
          //Adding initial data
          this.auxData = getDataFetch;
        } else {
          //prevent duplicated values
          getDataFetch.forEach((item) => {
            const isNewItem = this.auxData.find((itemAux) => {
              return item.id === itemAux.id;
            });
            if (!isNewItem) {
              //adding new data 
              this.auxData.unshift(item);
            }
          });
        }
      } else {
        //if there is not data, return []
        return this.auxData;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Don't `v-for`  the result of a method. `v-for` either `data` or `computed` members (state or derived state). Call methods to fetch data and/or modify state appropriately and use  `:key` attributes in `v-for`. Pay close attention to Vue's development warning messages. They're helpful.

Comment: @tao how could I do what I need to do? in my real code I have a component that returns data `<div v-for="item in addingData(myData)">  <!-- in My real code, "myData" should be the answer of an endpoint, is an setInterval, returns data like [{id:1},{id:2}] -->
  {{ item.id }}
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should be using `v-for` with `auxData` as that's what you're updating using the result of your API call (myData). As your API sends you new results, use a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) to run a function whenever a new update is made to then also update `auxData`

[updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-satdrb?file=src%2FApp.vue)

```js
watch: {
    myData(newData, oldData) {
      console.log('Entering AddingData', newData);
      if (newData.length !== 0) {
        if (this.auxData.length === 0) {
          this.auxData = newData;
        } else {
          newData.forEach((item) => {
            const isNewItem = this.auxData.find((itemAux) => {
              return item.id === itemAux.id;
            });
            if (!isNewItem) {
              this.auxData.unshift(item);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    },
  },
```

```html
<div v-for="item in auxData">
  {{ item.id }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding, You want to combined the unique objects in to an array getting from multiple API calls and show them into the template using `v-for`. If Yes, You can achieve that by using `computed` property.

As you are updating the `myData` every time you are getting response, You can push the unique objects into a separate array and then return that array using a computed property.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    combinedData: [],
    myData: []
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('First data');
      this.myData = [{ id: 3 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 1 }];
      this.pushData(this.myData)
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('second data');
        this.myData = [{ id: 4 }, { id: 4 }];
        this.pushData(this.myData)
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('Third data');
          this.myData = [];
          this.pushData(this.myData)
        }, 3000);
      }, 3000);
    }, 2000);
  },
  methods: {
    pushData(data) {
      data.forEach(obj => {
        if (!JSON.stringify(this.combinedData).includes(JSON.stringify(obj))) {
          this.combinedData.push(obj)
        }
      });
    }
  },
  computed: {
    finalData() {
        return this.combinedData
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in finalData">
    {{ item.id }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> in terms of performance this should be the output in the console.log

In terms of performance, you should use as few reactive data as possible, especially if your object has many properties. I would modify auxData directly.

```
 this.addingData([{ id: 3 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 1 }]);
```

Simplified addingData

```
addingData(getDataFetch) {
  // It's faster to get the id-s first
  let itemDict = new Set(this.auxData.map((m) => m.id));
  getDataFetch.forEach((item) => {
    if (!itemDict.has(item.id)) {
      this.auxData.unshift(item);
      itemDict.add(item.id);
    }
  });
},
```

And iterate over it

```
<div v-for="item in auxData">
  {{ item.id }}
</div>
```

Also watching object list can also cause performance issues. It should be used on primitive values.

[Example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-uyriik?file=src%2FApp.vue)